# ASP.NET MVC: Printing data from DataTable defined in Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have stored data from my database table to a DataTable dt. The DataTable is being filled in the controller. I am trying to get the DataTable data on the HTML page with paging. But somehow, the data is not being printed. It is perhaps because the DataTable is not getting accessed by the View from the Controller. Here's what I did:

**Controller:**

```
int pageindex = 0; 

    public DataTable GetRecords()
    {

        pageindex = pageindex + 20;

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BOConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Invoice ORDER BY OrderId ASC OFFSET (@pageindex) ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pageindex", pageindex);
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using System.Data;
@using System.Data.DataTable;

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Reports</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        <a href=@Url.Action("GetRecords", "Records")>Print Records</a><br />


    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <th>@col.Caption</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is throwing an error: 'Object reference not set to instance of an object.' at Models.Columns. I think this is because the DataTable is not getting filled (or referenced). How can I do this? How can I give a reference to the DataTable dt in the Controller to the View? What if there were multiple DataTables in the Controller?

Comment: Your controller is returning a `DataTable`?  Where do you return a `View`?

Comment: The view is missing @model directive for bind it to a specific model type, that model type must be the same of the model parameter passed to the view from the controller View() method

Comment: Can you clarify, @Sycraw? I don't understand completely.

Comment: For bind a view to a specific model is mandatory the  @ model directive, if I have a class called MyType, on the view representing an object of type MyType, the @ model MyType directive is requested in the view. To pass a MyType object to the view from the controller, this must have somethig like: MyType mt= new MyType; return View(mt). The same specifics are valid for any type of objects, custom or not.
In the view then, when you want to access at any mt porperties (the object passed from controller), @ Model.MyProp will do the magic (notice @ model directive is different from @ Model)

Comment: I had to separate @ from any keyword with a blank space for stackoverflow comment design (it thoght that they were a reference to StackOverflow users)